# Curve fitting with lmfit for Mossbauer spectroscopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, physics, curve-fitting

Im pretty new to lmfit and I keep running into this error. My dataset is pretty large ~27000 points of data from I gather:

[my error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh87r.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model
import pandas as pd

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300

# Define the Lorentzian function with a negative sign
def lorentzian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    return (-amp * wid ** 2 / ((x - cen) ** 2 + wid ** 2))

# Define the sum of two Lorentzian peaks
def multi_lorentzian(x, a1, c1, w1, a2, c2, w2):
    return (lorentzian(x, a1, c1, w1) + lorentzian(x, a2, c2, w2))

csv_names = ['Channel', 'Energy', 'Counts']
fp2 = "C:\\Users\\mfern\\Downloads\\Data_3_8.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(fp2, skiprows=23, names=csv_names).dropna()  # Remove rows with NaN values

xdata = df['Channel']
ydata = df['Counts']

model = Model(multi_lorentzian)

params = model.make_params(a1=0, c1=0, w1=0, a2=0, c2=0, w2=0)
params['a1'].min = 0
params['a2'].min = 0
params['w1'].min = 0
params['w2'].min = 0

result = model.fit(ydata, params=params, x=xdata)

# Print the fit report
print(result.fit_report())

# Plot the data and the fit curve
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, label='data', s=2, c='b')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
```

So if there is anyone that can enlighten me, I would greatly appreciate it [this is what my data looks like btw]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg0yq.png)

AND this is link to my data set (with google drive link):
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ho5b1iGV9_wft9h_e6xP9KRtQgGCufcD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608250/803359) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I think the error you are seeing may come from the dataset you are using. You didn't provide data, so it's hard to know for sure.

I think the general approach to the model you have is OK, but missing some features.  For one thing, your Lorentzian's will have a value of zero far from their centroids, whereas your Mossbauer data is around 25000.

More importantly, you definitely need to give somewhat realistic initial values for the parameters, and those values should not at the boundary you set.  If it is not obvious, setting all values to zero will give a model curve that looks nothing like your data.  I cannot stress this strongly enough: you absolutely must provide initial values that are reasonably close such that they can be changed by a small amount and give a noticeable change in the result of "data-model".

Since you didn't provide data, I made some up that looks sort of close ;), and used the builtin lmfit models, something like this, which might be a good start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit.models import ConstantModel, LorentzianModel
from lmfit.lineshapes import lorentzian

npts = 2001
velo = np.linspace(0, 1000.0, npts)
signal = (26900 + np.random.normal(size=npts, scale=100)
          - 80000. * lorentzian(velo, center=240, sigma=6)
          - 79000. * lorentzian(velo, center=790, sigma=7) )


# model = constant + 2 Lorentzians
model = ConstantModel() + LorentzianModel(prefix='p1_') + LorentzianModel(prefix='p2_')

# guess initial values
params = model.make_params(c=25000,
                           p1_center=250, p1_sigma=10, p1_amplitude=-10000,
                           p2_center=750, p2_sigma=10, p2_amplitude=-10000)

params['p1_amplitude'].max = 0  # enforce p1_amplitude < 0
params['p2_amplitude'].max = 0

out = model.fit(signal, params, x=velo)

print(out.fit_report())

plt.plot(velo, signal, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(velo, out.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will give a report of

```
[[Model]]
    ((Model(constant) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='p1_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='p2_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 109
    # data points      = 2001
    # variables        = 7
    chi-square         = 19912468.9
    reduced chi-square = 9986.19301
    Akaike info crit   = 18434.1141
    Bayesian info crit = 18473.3239
    R-squared          = 0.96651410
[[Variables]]
    c:             26897.4478 +/- 2.43041838 (0.01%) (init = 25000)
    p1_amplitude: -80171.1149 +/- 638.944430 (0.80%) (init = -10000)
    p1_center:     239.908167 +/- 0.04587653 (0.02%) (init = 250)
    p1_sigma:      5.99624015 +/- 0.06621609 (1.10%) (init = 10)
    p2_amplitude: -78808.0930 +/- 694.381394 (0.88%) (init = -10000)
    p2_center:     789.912879 +/- 0.05883249 (0.01%) (init = 750)
    p2_sigma:      6.99732305 +/- 0.08516581 (1.22%) (init = 10)
    p1_fwhm:       11.9924803 +/- 0.13243219 (1.10%) == '2.0000000*p1_sigma'
    p1_height:    -4255.87684 +/- 32.5617804 (0.77%) == '0.3183099*p1_amplitude/max(1e-15, p1_sigma)'
    p2_fwhm:       13.9946461 +/- 0.17033163 (1.22%) == '2.0000000*p2_sigma'
    p2_height:    -3584.99901 +/- 30.1429487 (0.84%) == '0.3183099*p2_amplitude/max(1e-15, p2_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(p2_amplitude, p2_sigma) = -0.7230
    C(p1_amplitude, p1_sigma) = -0.7211
    C(c, p2_amplitude)        = -0.2989
    C(c, p1_amplitude)        = -0.2800
    C(c, p2_sigma)            = +0.2133
    C(c, p1_sigma)            = +0.1998
```

and a plot of

[image]

Comment: oh yes now i understand what those parameters do, I wasn't sure what to set those as. Unfornately, I'm still having that same error. I'm sorry I didn't link my data in the first place, would appreciate any further help.

Comment: Your script still a) does not include an offset in Counts, b) sets initial parameter values VERY far from reasonable values, and c) sets initial values to the boundary value of zero.  You need to change your script so that it does none of those things. I suggest starting with the working example I posted and modifying that to use your data.  If you have problems with that, plot your data to make sure it is what you think it is, and convert from pandas Series to numpy ndarrays.

Comment: your a godsend, i used numpy to load in my csv file and adjusted my parameters, and came out pretty good. I really appreciate all your help!